# Ordered logit with independent variable only taking negative values

Tags: logistic

I have a continuous independent (explanatory) variable that takes on negative values only. How do I interpret a negative coefficient on this variable?
The dependent variable is ordered as 1,2,3.
Is it the usual interpretation that the log odds are lower as we move from 1 to 2 and then 2 to 3?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, there seems to be some confusion in whether your dependent or independent variable is always negative. Can you correct your question so that this will be clear, please?

Comment: Done. Sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the ordered logit is linear in the log-odds, so the fact that values of your explanatory variable are negative has no impact on the slope and its interpretation. If they are all negative I would use examples like going from -2 to -1 or -3 to -2, but otherwise there is no difference.

Comment: Thanks. So going from -2 to -1 reduces the log odds of being in category 2 vs. category 1 and so on? or is it if one goes from -1 to -2, the log odds of being in category 2 are lower than that of being in category 1?

Comment: If your explanatory variable increases by one unit (e.g. going from -2 to -1, as $-2 + 1 = -1$) and the coefficient is negative, then that will decrease the log odds of entering category 2 of your explained variable compared to category 1.

Comment: If your explanatory variable decreases by one unit (e.g. going from -1 to -2) and the coefficient is negative then the log odds of entering category 2 of your explained variable compared to category 1 will increase.